# Why is the form of a linear equation $ax + b = 0$ and not $ax - b = 0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The form of a linear equation in one variable ($x$) is:

$$ax + b = 0$$

Why is $b$ positive?

Why not the following form?

$$ax - b = 0$$

It seems both result in the same multiple of $x$, just a change in sign.

Comment: Are you under the impression that the $+$ sign means $b$ is positive? It does not. It means you add whatever value $b$ has to the result of multiplying $a$ by $x$.

Comment: Well if $b < 0$ then replace it with $b_0 = -b$. Now we have $ax+b_0=0 $ and it's in the desired form.

Comment: This is because $ax+b$ is in the canonical form of a polynomial. Compare this with $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$, for example.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Because $b$, the variable, can be either a positive number or a negative number. If it is a negative number, the equation will become $ax+(-b)=0$. A negative and a positive make a negative so ultimately, even if the form has a plus symbol, if the variable is negative, it will become minus. Positive is just more general.

Comment: $b$ is a parameter, not "the variable."

Comment: "If it is a negative number the equation will become ax + (-b) = 0"  No, it won't.  It will still be $ax+b =0$ but $b$ is negative.  Maybe it'd be helpful, and maybe it'd be utterly confusing, to say.   If $b< 0$ and $b = -d$ for some positive $d$ then $ax+b = ax + (-d)= ax -d$.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a convention; that's it's basically irrelevant.

In any of the canonical forms $ax+b=y, y-y_0=m(x-x_0)$ or $ax+by+c=0$, any of the constants could be replaced by their negatives.